# Add references to different Casperjs scripts in a single script

Tags: javascript, testing, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Suppose i have a Casperjs script.
Its actaully very long, so I wish to break it into different script, and refer those scripts in main start.js file.

Example, in 'start.js',  I wish to do this:

```
casper.start(url);
// casper.run 'script1.js'
// casper.run 'script2.js'
// casper.run 'script.js'
```

And other scripts, which are in the same directory as `script1.js, script2.js and script3.js`. So what is the syntax to call these scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to write small bash script for this purpose?
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
casperjs script1.js
casperjs script2.js
casperjs script3.js
```

This is a simple solution, but in this case your scripts have to be autonomous.

Comment: I thought of this, but then there were problems such that every time i would have to add [[ var casper = require('casper').create(); ]] and  [[ casper.run(); ]] so this is not a good practice. Can it be done the either way?